# How to slice today's data from Pandas Timeseries?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to slice today's data from pandas timeseries.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10000,1),columns=['A'],
                  index=pd.date_range('20140518',periods=10000,freq='T'))
```

Follwing seems to work fine:

```
df['2014-05-19']
```

But when I am using datetime to get today's date by using all the methods below

```
df[datetime.date.today()]
df[datetime.datetime.now()]
df[datetime.datetime.now().date()]
```

I get the following Keyerror message

```
KeyError: datetime.date(2014, 5, 19)
```

Detailed Error stack is as shown below

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
    489     def __getitem__(self, key):
    490         try:
--> 491             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    492             if isinstance(result, np.ndarray):
    493                 return self._constructor(result,index=[key]*len(result)).__finalize__(self)

C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\index.pyc in get_value(self, series, key)
   1228                 return self.get_value_maybe_box(series, key)
   1229             except (TypeError, ValueError, KeyError):
-> 1230                 raise KeyError(key)
   1231 
   1232     def get_value_maybe_box(self, series, key):

KeyError: datetime.date(2014, 5, 19)
```

Comment: Feels hacky, but does `df[str(pd.datetime.now().date())]` work?

Comment: Your datetime slice will result in an exact index call. So something like `datetime.datetime.now` will try to index something like : `2014-05-19 19:49:54` and datetime.datetime.now().date() will I think get converted to `2014-05-19 00:00:00` by `pandas` when it attemps the slice. Strings work because they do partial matching.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df[df.index.date == datetime.date.today()]
```